# Regex. Remove Code Statements from For Loop Block

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

Remove code statement from for loop block...

```
  for( UIComponent currentMenuItemComponent : menuBarComponent.getChildren() ) {
     String style = "";
     String selectedViewName = ( String )currentMenuItemComponent.getAttributes().get( ATTRIBUTE_View );
     logger.info( "Value of selectedViewName =" + selectedViewName );
     if( selectedViewName.equals( targetView ) ) {
        style = "selected";
        logger.info( "Value of style =" + style );
     }
```

I want to remove `logger.info` statements from for loop block. Is this possible ?

I have already used the expression

```
(if|else)(.*)(\r?\n)([\s-]*)(logger.info)(\( \")(.*)(\" \);)
```

to remove them from if statements in Notepad++. I am looking for a way to remover from the **for** block

**Update:** If possible with a python script please help me out.

Comment: Well, If you can do it for `if` statement, what's the big deal in a `for loop`?

Comment: Because its not in the next line... It can be anywhere is the for loop block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to the other question you asked on locating `System.out.println` here: [Remove System.out statements from For Loops blocks only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508605/remove-system-out-statements-from-for-loops-blocks-only).

Referring to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556782/1395668), the only difference is the PMD query is different. Here is the new one:

```
//ForStatement/Statement/descendant-or-self::
       Statement[./StatementExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image="logger.info"]]
```

Replace the other query in the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` element in `custom.xml` in my answer. All other steps are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you cannot do with regexes, at least not with Notepad++'s regex engine.

Consider the following:

```
for (...)
{
   foo();
   logger.info(baz)
   if (bar())
   {
       logger.info(spam)
   }
   logger.info(ham)
}
```

You would need to recursively keep track of the nesting level of braces `{...}` that your program is currently in to determine whether any `logger.info()` belongs to the correct block. And most regex engines can't handle recursion.

Even if you were using one that can (like .NET), it would still be a nightmare. Imagine this:

```
    for (...)
    {
       foo();
       logger.info(baz)
//       if (bar())
//       {
       if (badabing()) {
           logger.info(spam)
       }
       logger.info(ham)
    }
```

*Now*  try and keep track with nesting...