# Remove System.out statements from For Loops blocks only

Tags: java, python, regex, perl, code-editor

Any way to remove them **only from** the for loop blocks in a file easily...

**Before**:

```
for( ... ) {
...
System.out.println("string");
...
System.out.println("string");
...
}
```

**After**:

```
for( ... ) {
...
... 
...
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use a regular expression and search-replace.

Comment: that depends on what you mean by "in loops"  If you call `method()` from a loop somewhere in your code,, do you want to remove all the comments from `method`?

Comment: May I ask why one would like to remove comments from source code? Is it about counting lines of code or something?

Comment: @home He might have found some comments throughout the for loops that say something that doesn't need to be said. If the previous developer left those comments in every for loop he would be right to remove them.

Comment: @sdasdadas: of course, I agreee. But would you look for an automated approach in that case :-) Do not missunderstand me, I did not downvote the question, just interested...

Comment: @home Sorry for the wrong question.... I have updated it.

Comment: @home That's a good point.

Comment: What about `/* for (...) {  System.out.println("System.out.println"); } */`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is tricky: Which closing brace closes the `for`-loop? Either you parse the whole code, or you use some heuristic. In the below solution, I require the intendation of the closing brace to be the same as the intendation of the `for` keyword:

```
$ perl -nE'
    if( /^(\s*)for\b/ .. /^$ws\}/ ) {
      $ws = $1 // $ws;
      /^\s*System\.out\.println/ or print;
    } else { print }'
```

This uses the flip-flop operator `COND1 .. COND2`. The script can be used as a simple filter

```
$ perl -nE'...' <source >processed
```

or with backup functionality:

```
$ perl -i.bak -nE'...' source
```

(creates file `source.bak` as backup).

<del>Only tested against the example input; not againts a sensible test suite.</del>
This script passes the GLES Prateek Nina test.

To run this script on all Java files in a directory, do

```
$ perl -i.bak -nE'...' *.java
```

#### Edit

On Windows systems, the delimiter has to be changed to `"`. Also, we have to do all globbing ourselves.

```
> perl -nE"if(/^(\s*)for\b/../^$ws\}/){$ws=$1//$ws;/^\s*System\.out\.println/ or print}else{print}BEGIN{@ARGV=$#ARGV?@ARGV:glob$ARGV[0]}" *.java
```

#### Edit 2

Here is an implementation of the brace-counting algorithm I outlined in the comments. This solution does backups as well. The command line arguments will be interpreted as glob expressions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

clean($_) for map glob($_), @ARGV;

sub clean {
    local @ARGV = @_;
    local $^I = ".bak";
    my $depth = 0;
    while (<>) {
        $depth ||= /^\s*for\b/ ? "0 but true" : 0;
        my $delta = ( ()= /\{/g ) - ( ()= /\}/g );
        $depth += $delta if $depth && $delta;
        $depth = 0 if $depth < 0;
        print unless $depth && /^\s*System\.out\.println/;
    }
    return !!1;
}
```

This doesn't do comments either. This will only reckognize `System.out.println`-statements that *start* a new line.

Example usage: `> perl thisScript.pl *.java`.

Here is a test file with pseudo-java syntax that I used for testing. All lines marked with `XXX` will be gone once the script has run.

```
/** Java test suite **/

bare block {
    System.out.println(...); // 1 -- let stand
}

if (true) {
    for (foo in bar) {
        System.out.println; // 2 XXX
        if (x == y) {
            // plz kill this
            System.out.println // 3 XXX
        } // don't exit here
        System.out.println // 4 XXX
    }
}

for (...) {
    for {
        // will this be removed?
        System.out.println // 5 XXX
    }
}

/* pathological cases */

// intendation
for (...) { System.out.println()/* 6 */} 

// intendation 2
for (...)
{
    if (x)
    {
        System.out.println // 7 XXX
    }}

// inline weirdness
for (...) {
    // "confuse" script here
    foo = new baz() {void qux () {...}
    };
    System.out.println // 8 XXX
}
```

№ 1 should stay, and does. Statement № 6 should be removed; but these scripts are incapable of doing so.

Comment: Of course, this won't work as expected if there are other blocks inside the `for` loop as well: `for { if (blah) { xyz; } System.out.println(); }`

Comment: Just implemented major bugfix. It passes the @GLESPrateekNina test and produces identical output, without hardcoding filenames, but with backups!

Comment: @Zaid I don't quite understand your comment; please elaborate. Other blocks work fine, as long as proper intendation is used.

Comment: Assuming proper indentation, all's well. Just wanted to highlight a potential failure mode, nothing more.

Comment: Do you think `PPI` could be manipulated to suit the OP's needs here?

Comment: @Zaid, PPI doesn't parse Java. The OP is looking for a Java parser.

Comment: @ikegami : I was expecting to hear that... it would've been kinda cool to see PPI parsing Java as well once it was bent backwards.

Comment: @amon Its giving an error `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1` . Sorry I am new to perl.

Comment: @Debajyoti What OS are you using? The script was tested on Linux, in bash. You can remove all newlines, this should make using the script easier. On Windows (cmd.exe), change the delimiter from `'` to `"`.

Comment: @amon `Can't open *.java: Invalid argument`. After changing from `'` to `"`

Can you tell me what to add to the pl script by @gles-prateek-nina so that it doesn't exit early.

Comment: @Debajyoti Ah yes, I forgot that "globbing" is a *luxury*. The above update manages that without changing the contract of the application. I will take a deeper look into GLES' code, and see if I can fix that. Shouldn't take to long…

Comment: @Debajyoti I added another script that will do the job; this time by counting opening and closing braces. The sub `clean` can be used as a drop-in replacement in the @GlesPrateekNina script, but make sure to comment out his final for-loop; else you clutter your file system with empty files. The sub will also add backup functionality.

Comment: @amon - Thanks a lot. Just one last question... how to *not* create the backup file. Or create the .bak files at a completely different location.

Comment: @Debajyoti The inplace editing systems uses a lot of magic. To switch it off, remove the `-i.bak` command line switch, or the `local $^I` statement in the script. However, backups are a good idea, my scripts are in no way perfect. You could bulk-copy all backup files via `perl -MFile::Copy -E"$target=shift;@a=map glob($_),@ARGV;for(@a){$n=$_;s/\.bak$//;move$n=>qq[$target/$_]}" C:/path/to/target/dir *.bak` Or something similar (sadly, untested.)

Comment: @amon Just one more help. Please. What should the regex be in that clean function in your script if I wanted to remove all SOP statements from all non-void (with a return statement) methods.

Comment: @Debajyoti That isn't really possible, as this would require us to know if there will be a return statement on a coming line once we encounter a SOP. Also, method declarations aren't exactly easy to find in Java. You need a full parser here, not just one magic regex. The Andrew Alcock answer may be more applicable here. Otherwise, this is the stuff new questions are made of…

Comment: Tried with `(public|private|protected)\s*(?!void|class|abstract|static void)\w` seems to be working...

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest a two-fold approach using the static code analyser [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) to locate the problem statements and a simple script to remove the lines. All source and configuration is included below, **EDIT** including Python and Groovy alternatives.

PMD has an extension mechanism allowing [new rules to be added](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.1/howtowritearule.html) very simply using a simple XPath expression. In my implementation below, I use:

```
        //WhileStatement/Statement/descendant-or-self::
            Statement[./StatementExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image="System.out.println"]]
        |
        //ForStatement/Statement/descendant-or-self::
            Statement[./StatementExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image="System.out.println"]]
```

The benefits of using this approach are:

- **No regular expressions**
- [Graphical editor](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.1/howtowritearule.html) to develop and refine rules - you could fine-tune the rules I have given to deal with any other scenarios you have
- Handles all weird formatting of the Java source - PMD uses the JavaCC compiler to understand the structure of all valid Java files
- Handles where the `System.out.println` is in a conditional within the loop - to any depth
- Handles where statements are split over multiple lines.
- Can be used within [Eclipse](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/) and [IntelliJ](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/CONTEST/PMDPlugin)

Instructions

1. Create a PMD rule in a custom ruleset.

   - Create a directory `rulesets/java` somewhere on the `CLASSPATH` - it could be under the working directory if "." is on the path.
   - In this directory, create a ruleset XML file called `custom.xml` containing:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <ruleset name="Custom"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

         <description>Detecting System.out.println's</description>
         <rule name="LoopedSystemOutPrintlns"
               message="System.out.println() statements in a for or while loop"
               language="java"
               class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule">
           <description>
              Find System.out.println() statements in for or while loops.
           </description>
           <priority>1</priority>
           <properties>
             <property name="xpath">
             <value>
               <![CDATA[
     //WhileStatement/Statement/descendant-or-self::
         Statement[./StatementExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image="System.out.println"]]
     |
     //ForStatement/Statement/descendant-or-self::
         Statement[./StatementExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image="System.out.println"]]
               ]]>
               </value>
             </property>
           </properties>
         </rule>
     </ruleset>
     ```
   - Create a rulesets.properties file containing the following line:

     ```
     rulesets.filenames=rulesets/java/custom.xml
     ```
   - Great! PMD now has been configured with your new rule that identifies all occasions of a `System.out.println` inside any loop anywhere in your code. Your ruleset is now called 'java-custom' because it's 'custom.xml' in the directory 'java'
2. Run PMD on your codebase selecting just your ruleset, java-custom. Use the XML report to get both the starting *and* ending lines. Capture the result in the file "violations.xml":

   ```
   $ pmd -d <SOURCEDIR> -f xml -r java-custom > violations.xml
   ```

   Produces a file similar to:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <pmd version="5.0.1" timestamp="2013-01-28T11:22:25.688">
   <file name="SOURCEDIR/Example.java">
   <violation beginline="7" endline="11" begincolumn="13" endcolumn="39" rule="LoopedSystemOutPrintlns" ruleset="Custom" class="Example" method="bar" priority="1">
   System.out.println() statements in a for or while loop
   </violation>
   <violation beginline="15" endline="15" begincolumn="13" endcolumn="38" rule="LoopedSystemOutPrintlns" ruleset="Custom" class="Example" method="bar" priority="1">
   System.out.println() statements in a for or while loop
   </violation>
   <violation beginline="18" endline="18" begincolumn="13" endcolumn="38" rule="LoopedSystemOutPrintlns" ruleset="Custom" class="Example" method="bar" priority="1">
   System.out.println() statements in a for or while loop
   </violation>
   <violation beginline="20" endline="21" begincolumn="17" endcolumn="39" rule="LoopedSystemOutPrintlns" ruleset="Custom" class="Example" method="bar" priority="1">
   System.out.println() statements in a for or while loop
   </violation>
   </file>
   </pmd>
   ```

   You can use this report to check that PMD has identified the correct statements.
3. Create a Python script (NOTE: a Groovy alternative is given at the bottom of the Answer) to read in the violations XML file and process the source files

   - Create a file called `remover.py` on a directory in the classpath
   - Add the following Python to it:

     ```
     from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
     from os import rename, path
     from sys import argv

     def clean_file(source, target, violations):
         """Read file from source outputting all lines, *except* those in the set
         violations, to the file target"""
         infile  = open(source, 'r' )
         outfile = open(target, "w")
         for num, line in enumerate(infile.readlines(), start=1):
             if num not in violations:
                 outfile.write(line)
         infile.close()
         outfile.close()


     def clean_all(pmd_xml):
         """Read a PMD violations XML file; for each file identified, remove all 
         lines that are marked as violations"""
         tree = ElementTree()
         tree.parse(pmd_xml)
         for file in tree.findall("file"):
             # Create a list of lists. Each inner list identifies all the lines
             # in a single violation.
             violations = [ range(int(violation.attrib['beginline']), int(violation.attrib['endline'])+1) for violation in file.findall("violation")]
             # Flatten the list of lists into a set of line numbers
             violations = set( i for j in violations for i in j )

             if violations:
                 name = file.attrib['name']
                 bak  = name + ".bak"
                 rename(name, bak)
                 clean_file(bak, name, violations)

     if __name__ == "__main__":
         if len(argv) != 2 or not path.exists(argv[1]):
             exit(argv[0] + " <PMD violations XML file>")
         clean_all(argv[1])
     ```
4. Run the Python script. This will rename matching files by adding a ".bak", then rewrite the Java file without the offending lines. **This may be destructive so ensure your files are properly backed up first**. In particular, don't run the script twice in a row - the second time round will naively remove the same line numbers, even though they have already been removed:

   ```
   $ python remover.py violations.xml
   ```

---

**EDIT**

For those who prefer a more Java-oriented script to remove `System.out.println` statements from the `violations.xml`, I present the following Groovy:

```
    def clean_file(source, target, violations) {
        new File(target).withWriter { out ->
            new File(source).withReader { reader ->
                def i = 0
                while (true) {
                    def line = reader.readLine()
                    if (line == null) {
                        break
                    }  else {
                        i++
                        if(!(i in violations)) {
                            out.println(line)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def linesToRemove(file_element) {
        Set lines = new TreeSet()
        for (violation in file_element.children()) {
            def i = Integer.parseInt(violation.@beginline.text())
            def j = Integer.parseInt(violation.@endline.text())
            lines.addAll(i..j)
        }
        return lines
    }

    def clean_all(file_name) {
        def tree = new XmlSlurper().parse(file_name)
        for (file in tree.children()) {
            def violations = linesToRemove(file)
            if (violations.size() > 0) {
                def origin = file.@name.text()
                def backup = origin + ".bak"
                new File(origin).renameTo(new File(backup))
                clean_file(backup, origin, violations)
            }
        }
    }

    clean_all("violations.xml")
```

---

As a general observation, `System.out.println` calls are not necessarily the problem - it may be that your statements are of the form `"Calling method on " + obj1 + " with param " + obj2 + " -> " + (obj1.myMethod(obj2))` and the real cost is both the string concatenation (better with StringBuffer/StringBuilder) and the cost of the method call.

Comment: is there a way to get around the python part? Like, an extension or an eclipse-plugin that uses PMD to allow custom code transformations like that? The Eclipse plugin you cite is great for custom rules, but only supports detection :-(

Comment: I used Python because IMHO it's an easier way than Java to knock up a script to read violations.xml and then manipulate the source files. Of course, this can be replaced by Java (or any other language). Do you have specific platform issues with Python (which is by default installed in most Linux flavours and Mac OSX)? I'll see if I can knock something up in Groovy in any case.

Comment: The PMD plugin to eclipse does not, to the best of my knowledge, have any facility to be extended to refactor/modify code. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

**1. nested `for` loops corrected**

**2. `.java` files now fetched recursively**

**Note:**

> When you are confident with the code, replace line 45: `open( hanw , "+>".$file.".txt" );`
>
> with this line: `open( hanw , "+>".$file );`

***application.pl***

```
use strict;
use File::Find qw( finddepth );
our $root = "src/";
our $file_data = {};
our @java_files;

finddepth( sub {
  if( $_ eq '.' || $_ eq '..' ) {
    return;
  } else {
    if( /\.java$/i ) {
      push( @java_files , $File::Find::name );
    }
  }
} , $root );

sub clean {
  my $file = shift;
  open( hanr , $file );
  my @input_lines = <hanr>;
  my $inside_for = 0;

  foreach( @input_lines ) {
    if( $_ =~ /(\s){0,}for(\s){0,}\((.*)\)(\s){0,}\{(\s){0,}/ ) {
      $inside_for++;
      push( @{$file_data->{$file}} , $_ );
    } elsif( $inside_for > 0 ) {
        if( $_ =~ /(\s){0,}System\.out\.println\(.*/ ) {
        } elsif( $_ =~ /(\s){0,}\}(\s){0,}/ ) {
          $inside_for--;
          push( @{$file_data->{$file}} , $_ );
        } else {
          push( @{$file_data->{$file}} , $_ );
        }
    } else {
      push( @{$file_data->{$file}} , $_ );
    }
  }
}

foreach ( @java_files ) {
  $file_data->{$_} = [];
  clean( $_ );
}

foreach my $file ( keys %$file_data ) {
  open( hanw , "+>".$file.".txt" );
  foreach( @{$file_data->{$file}} ) {
    print hanw $_;
  }
}
```

***data1.java***

```
class Employee {
  /* code */
  public void Employee() {
    System.out.println("string");
    for( ... ) {
      System.out.println("string");
      /* code */
      System.out.println("string");
      for( ... ) {
        System.out.println("string");
        /* code */
        System.out.println("string");
      }
    }
  }
}

for( ... ) {
  System.out.println("string");
  /* code */
  System.out.println("string");
}
```

***data2.java***

```
for( ... ) {
  /* code */
  System.out.println("string");
  /* code */
  System.out.println("string");
  /* code */
  for( ... ) {
    System.out.println("string");
    /* code */
    System.out.println("string");
    for( ... ) {
      System.out.println("string");
      /* code */
      System.out.println("string");
    }
  }
}

public void display() {
  /* code */
  System.out.println("string");
  for( ... ) {
    System.out.println("string");
    /* code */
    System.out.println("string");
    for( ... ) {
      System.out.println("string");
      /* code */
      System.out.println("string");
    }
  }
}
```

***data1.java.txt***

```
class Employee {
  /* code */
  public void Employee() {
    System.out.println("string");
    for( ... ) {
      /* code */
      for( ... ) {
        /* code */
      }
    }
  }
}

for( ... ) {
  /* code */
}
```

***data2.java.txt***

```
for( ... ) {
  /* code */
  /* code */
  /* code */
  for( ... ) {
    /* code */
    for( ... ) {
      /* code */
    }
  }
}

public void display() {
  /* code */
  System.out.println("string");
  for( ... ) {
    /* code */
    for( ... ) {
      /* code */
    }
  }
}
```

[image: image-1]

Comment: Do test the code :D it is inspirational because modern compilers also have similar passes when parsing source codes. I upvoted your question because data parsing is my favourite topic, and I will soon start working on compilers using C.

Comment: How to run this script on all .java files in a directory and write it on the file itself or a backup... And it didn't work properly if there is a for loop inside another for loop. PLZ HELP

Comment: Dear @GLESPrateekNina. You said: “It is more safe, neat and accurate”. Aside from the fact that our solutions produce identical output, I would like to address *neat*: Wherever you `push`, you could just as well `print`; saving memory and complexity. Your big regex looks obfuscated. Written *neatly* (and with unneccessary captures removed), it reads `/\s* for \s* \(.*\) \s* \{ \s*/x`. About *safe*: That regex fails to match if somebody puts the opening curly on a new line; there are such coding styles. Neither of us manages multiple `}` on one line. A *safe* solution might also handle comments

Comment: Just ran the code through my brain; aside from different regexes, we describe the same algorithm. However, you chocke once a `for`-loop contains inner blocks (e.q. `if`s). The closing braces of these would cause your parser to exit the parsed `for` too early. You could do something like `$inside_for ||= /for.../ ? "0 but true" : 0; $inside_for++ if $inside_for && /\{/; $inside_for-- if $inside_for > 0 && /\}/; print unless $inside_for && /^\s*System\.out.../;`

Comment: @gles-prateek-nina I tested it out... Its working fine... Just wanted to make sure if you had anything to add from Amon's inputs.

Comment: I noticed it exits early as Amon said.

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking to parse Java. A quick Google search reveals, [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/), a Java 1.5 parser written in Java.